# How can I scroll to a specified line number of a RichTextBox control using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

How can I scroll to a specified line number of a RichTextBox control using C#? It's the WinForms version.

Comment: I believe you can do with Win32 API. See
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/VbNetScrolling.aspx
To do it with C#, you will have to implement window procedure for RichTextBox Control:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.wndproc.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
    void ScrollToLine(int lineNumber)
    {
        if (lineNumber > richTextBox1.Lines.Count()) return;

        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Find(richTextBox1.Lines[lineNumber]);
        richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
    }
```

This will not work perfectly if you have lots of repetition within your RichTextBox. I do hope that it might be of some use to you.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what's needed.

Comment: This seems dangerous to me. When the wanted line occours more than once, your code will always jump to the first occourance.

Comment: For long text this doesn't work as it will fine the first line that has the same text.

Answer (score 7):

With this code the cursor jumps to the first column in the wanted line.

**It works perfectly in any case**, even when the wanted line occurs several times.

```
void GotoLine(int wantedLine_zero_based) // int wantedLine_zero_based = wanted line number; 1st line = 0
{
    int index = this.RichTextbox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(wantedLine_zero_based);
    this.RichTextbox.Select(index, 0);
    this.RichTextbox.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

Comment: Great job spent hours trying to figure this out. this one worked for my needs. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, if it has a method for this, but how about counting the linebreaks in the `Text` and then set the caret (via `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength`) and `ScrollToCaret()`?

Answer (score -2):

Would it help in this situation to split up the text?
For example:

`string[] lines = myRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');

int linesCount = lines.Length;`

This will tell you the number of lines.

Comment: Hey @TeenMrDragon. This question was posed a few years ago and as you can see has an accepted answer. Your answer doesn't quite assist the original poster since the original post asks how to scroll to a specified line. Take another look to see if you can figure out a better solution. I'm downvoting for now but I'll upvote if you can answer the question. Send me a comment here when you've edited it and I'll take a look.