# How can I change a numericUpDown1 value and that it will move to the next word in a rcihTextBox1 text?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
void lvnf_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection items =
                 listViewCostumControl1.lvnf.SelectedItems;

            results = new List<int>();

            foreach (ListViewItem item in items)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(item.Text);//File.ReadAllText(listViewCostumControl1.lvnf.Items[listViewCostumControl1.lvnf.SelectedIndices[listViewCostumControl1.lvnf.FocusedItem.Index]].Text);
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(item.Text);//listViewCostumControl1.lvnf.Items[listViewCostumControl1.lvnf.SelectedIndices[listViewCostumControl1.lvnf.FocusedItem.Index]].Text);

                lblfilesizeselected.Text = ExtensionMethods.ToFileSize(fi.Length);
                lblfilesizeselected.Visible = true;
                filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fi.FullName);
                string words = textBox1.Text;
                string[] splittedwords = words.Split(new string[]
                { ",," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                foreach (string myword in splittedwords)
                {
                    HighlightPhrase(richTextBox1, myword, Color.Yellow);
                    lblviewerselectedfile.Text = results.Count.ToString();
                    lblviewerselectedfile.Visible = true;
                    if (results.Count > 0)
                    {
                        numericUpDown1.Maximum = results.Count;
                        numericUpDown1.Enabled = true;
                        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = results[(int)numericUpDown1.Value];
                        richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And :

```
void HighlightPhrase(RichTextBox box, string phrase, Color color)
    {
        int pos = box.SelectionStart;
        string s = box.Text;
        for (int ix = 0; ;)
        {
            int jx = s.IndexOf(phrase, ix, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (jx < 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                box.SelectionStart = jx;
                box.SelectionLength = phrase.Length;
                box.SelectionColor = color;
                ix = jx + 1;
                results.Add(jx);
            }
        }
        box.SelectionStart = pos;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
```

And in numericUpDown1_ValueChanged I want to be able to make the richTextBox1 to scroll to the result number if the numericUpDown1 value is 1 "jump" scroll to the first highlight word then if the value 2 scroll a bit down to the second word and so on.

I tried this but it does nothing the richTextBox1 never scroll to the next word :

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (results.Count > 0)
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
                richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();

            }
        }
```

Maybe I need somehow to use also the results List to make it scroll to the right word ?

screenshot of the richTextBox1 and the numericUpDown1(Select result number)

[image: richTextBox1 and the numericUpDown1]

This is what I tried I added this class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Search_Text_In_Files
{
    public class TextSearcher
    {
        private BindingSource m_bsMatches = null;
        private RichTextBox m_Rtb = null;

        public TextSearcher(RichTextBox rtb) : this(rtb, Color.Yellow, Color.Red) { }
        public TextSearcher(RichTextBox rtb, Color selectionColor, Color currentColor)
        {
            m_Rtb = rtb;
            SelectionColor = selectionColor;
            CurrentColor = currentColor;
        }

        public string CurrentKeywords { get; private set; } = string.Empty;
        public bool CaseSensitive { get; set; } = true;
        public int CurrentIndex => m_bsMatches.Position;
        public Match CurrentMatch => (Match)m_bsMatches.Current;
        public MatchCollection Matches { get; private set; }
        public Color SelectionColor { get; set; }
        public Color CurrentColor { get; set; }

        public void GotoMatch(int position)
        {
            SelectText(false);
            m_bsMatches.Position = Math.Max(Math.Min(m_bsMatches.Count, position), 0);
            SelectText(true);
        }
        public void NextMatch()
        {
            SelectText(false);
            if (m_bsMatches != null && m_bsMatches.Position == m_bsMatches.Count - 1)
            {
                m_bsMatches.MoveFirst();
            }
            else { m_bsMatches.MoveNext(); }
            SelectText(true);
        }

        public void PreviousMatch()
        {
            SelectText(false);
            if (m_bsMatches != null && m_bsMatches.Position > 0)
            {
                m_bsMatches.MovePrevious();
            }
            else { m_bsMatches.MoveLast(); }
            SelectText(true);
        }

        public int Search(string keywords)
        {
            if (CurrentKeywords.Equals(keywords)) return Matches.Count;
            m_bsMatches?.Dispose();
            CurrentKeywords = keywords;
            var options = RegexOptions.Multiline |
                         (CaseSensitive ? RegexOptions.IgnoreCase : RegexOptions.None);
            Matches = Regex.Matches(m_Rtb.Text, keywords, options);
            if (Matches != null)
            {
                m_Rtb.SelectAll();
                m_Rtb.SelectionColor = m_Rtb.ForeColor;
                m_Rtb.SelectionStart = 0;
                m_bsMatches = new BindingSource(Matches, null);
                SelectKeywords();
                return Matches.Count;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        private void SelectKeywords()
        {
            foreach (Match m in Matches)
            {
                SelectText(false);
                NextMatch();
            }
            m_bsMatches.MoveFirst();
        }
        private void SelectText(bool current)
        {
            m_Rtb.Select(CurrentMatch.Index, CurrentMatch.Length);
            m_Rtb.SelectionColor = current ? CurrentColor : SelectionColor;
        }
    }
}
```

In form1 top :

```
private TextSearcher matchFinder = null;
```

In form1 constructor :

```
matchFinder = new TextSearcher(richTextBox1, Color.Yellow, Color.Red);
```

In form1 in the listview selectedindexchanged event :

```
void lvnf_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection items =
                 listViewCostumControl1.lvnf.SelectedItems;

            results = new List<int>();

            foreach (ListViewItem item in items)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(item.Text);
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(item.Text);

                lblfilesizeselected.Text = ExtensionMethods.ToFileSize(fi.Length);
                lblfilesizeselected.Visible = true;
                filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fi.FullName);

                string words = textBox1.Text;
                string[] splittedwords = words.Split(new string[]
                { ",," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
              
                    numericUpDown1.Maximum = matchFinder.Search("form1");                
            }
        }
```

And the numericupdown1 value changed event :

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (matchFinder.Matches.Count > 0)
            {
                matchFinder.GotoMatch((int)numericUpDown1.Value - 1);
            }
        }
```

I want that when I select item in the listview selectedindexchanged event it will highlight the words in the richTextBox1 and then using the numericUpDown1 value changed event to travel between the highlighted words.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323105/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specified-line-number-of-a-richtextbox-control-using-c/37657901

Comment: [How to highlight a word or phrase with a color different from all the other selections in a RichTextBox text?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62012582/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi how do I use it in my code ? Edited my question with what I tried. It does highlight the first selected item file in the listview selected index changed event but then when I select other items it's not highlighting them again. also the numericUpDown1 value changed is not working the value always 0.